# Remove specific element from list

Tags: r, list

Consider the following list as an example:

```
l <- list(list("a","b"),"c", list("d","e"))
```

If I would like to remove the list of length 1. I tought I could do it like this:

```
l <- lapply(l, function(e){if(length(e) > 1)e})
```

but this results in this:

```
> l

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "a"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "b"


[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "d"

[[3]][[2]]
[1] "e"
```

What is the most elegant way to remove specific elements of a list?

Comment: You can use this: `l[lapply(l, length) > 1]`

Comment: Similarly, `l[lengths(l) > 1]` will do.

Comment: Nice that does the job. Would you like to post that as an answer and I can mark it as correct?

Comment: @jazzuro No this does not work. As applying length() to a list returns the a single value (the length of the hole list), not a vector.

Comment: @John @jazzurro suggested to use `lengths` not `length`.

Comment: @john If you have time, check `?lengths`. @PoGibas Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Ah sorry my bad. Also was not aware that this function exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply posting [PoGibas'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48282612/remove-specific-element-from-list#comment83548916_48282612) and [jazzurro's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48282612/remove-specific-element-from-list#comment83549049_48282612) as an answer to have the question closed. if one of you feel like posting your comment as an answer please feel free to delete this answer.

l <- list(list("a","b"),"c", list("d","e"))

[PoGibas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48282612/remove-specific-element-from-list#comment83548916_48282612),

```
l[lapply(l, length) > 1]
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]]
#> [1] "a"
#> [[1]][[2]]
#> [1] "b"
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]][[1]]
#> [1] "d"
#> [[2]][[2]]
#> [1] "e"
```

[jazzurro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48282612/remove-specific-element-from-list#comment83549049_48282612),

```
l[lengths(l) > 1]
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]]
#> [1] "a"
#> [[1]][[2]]
#> [1] "b"
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]][[1]]
#> [1] "d"
#> [[2]][[2]]
#> [1] "e"
```

also,

```
identical(l[lapply(l, length) > 1], l[lengths(l) > 1])
#> [1] TRUE
```